# Name for a conversation where two people are talking about two things, without their knowledge

Tags: writing, literary-techniques

The show Arrested Development uses a writing technique I haven't seen very often, but I find very interesting. The idea is that two people will have a conversation where they are both talking from two completely different contexts, the conversation works in either context, and they both end without ever realizing they didn't understand each other.

Example: in this clip George Michael is shy about the fact that he has a crush on his teacher. His aunt thinks he doesn't want to admit that he sees his teacher as a mother-figure and confidant. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6Ap3xNLg4w

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: Though some of the answers there might apply here, none but the second-to-last answer even remotely answers the question there: _What is a word for the **sensation** when ... you realize you were both talking about different things?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people speaking are **at cross purposes**.

> *at cross purposes*
>
> If two people are at cross purposes, they think they are talking about or trying to do the same thing as each other,
> but they are actually talking about or trying to do different things.
>
> - *They had been talking at cross purposes earlier, he realized.*

[[Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+cross+purposes)]

> *at cross-purposes*
>
> with opposing viewpoints; with goals that interfere with each other.
>
> - *We are arguing at cross-purposes. We aren't even discussing the same thing.*

[[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+cross+purposes)]

Answer (score 1):

The phrases "*to be/talk at cross purposes*" can be used for this type of misunderstanding.

> ([The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/talk+at+cross+purposes))
> **be/talk at cross ˈpurposes** (of two people or groups) misunderstand what the other is referring to or trying to do
> ♦ Mary and I spoke about Anne for a minute or two before I realized we were talking at cross purposes: I meant Anne Smith and Mary meant Anne Harris.

Comment: Already given...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is what I just saw, after my answer had been clocked in.

Comment: Do you suggest I delete?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't be so inconsiderate as to say that I wouldn't mind if you did,  (ha! ha! ha!), and in fact, I'd be upset if you did that on the ground of the similarity with my answer. No,  I do not want that at all; it wouldn't be right; if someone should, in any case, delete an answer it should be I. I think that people can see the time difference: there is no risk of your being dubbed a plagiarist. I am the only one at risk.

Answer (score -1):

This is related to the idea of the ***double entendre***, which is a phrase that has two distinct meanings. A double entendre is usually a short phrase that's intended to have a humorous effect, as there's usually a fairly innocuous meaning which can be contrasted with a more bawdy interpretation (like when Tobias paints himself blue, and proudly proclaims that "he blue himself"). Here, we have a conversation that is full of double entendres, as both parties are interpreting the statements being made in completely different contexts. Arrested Development has lots of wordplay many, many examples of double entendres, and this example takes it to the extreme, crafting an entire conversation out of double entrendres with two entirely diferent meanings.